# MongoDB aggregation - operator to read in documents

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, nestjs, aggregation, data-ingestion

Since Mongo only supports *one* `$text` field per aggregation pipeline (inside the first `$match` stage), that means you can't perform a logical AND, since you can't `$and` the results of multiple `$text` searches.

```
// Fails due to "too many text expressions"
db.Employees.aggregate([
    {$match: {$and: [
        {$text: {$search: "senior"}},
        {$text: {$search: "manager"}}
    ]}}
])
```

Therefore I need to perform multiple separate `$text` searches, combine the results in my NodeJS code, and pass that result set back into an aggregation pipeline for further processing (e.g. `$addFields`, `$match`, `$sort`).

Is there a way to do something like...

```
let results1 = db.Employees.find({"$text":{"$search":"senior"}}, {"score":{"$meta":"textScore"}})
let results2 = db.Employees.find({"$text":{"$search":"manager"}}, {"score":{"$meta":"textScore"}})
let combinedResults = _.intersectionWith(results1, results2, _.isEqual)
let finalResults = /* pass combinedResults into aggregation pipeline and execute it */
```

Something like the opposite of the [$out operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/), where I'm reading in a result set instead.

I'm using NestJS and Mongoose if that helps.

Comment: Are you looking for phrase kind of search where document contains `Senior manager`?

Comment: I've looked into the phrase search https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/text/#phrases but I want it to match even if the terms aren't right next to each other - so the document should contain `senior` in some field, and `manager` in some field. They could be within the same field, but they don't have to be. Better example might be a search like "James AND manager"

Comment: Is there a way to directly feed a predefined array of documents into an aggregation pipeline though?

Comment: Unfortunately only one text is allowed per aggregation. Are you ok to use regex?

Comment: I could be down for some regex - would that let me stick everything into an aggregation?

Answer (score 0):

There are [restrictions](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/text/index.html#restrictions) in `$text`, that you already know,

There is a option if you have limited fields, using [$regexMatch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/regexMatch/index.html), I am not sure, in how many fields you have text index, but with this you can combine match conditions with `$and` operator for multiple fields,

**Example Data:**

```
[
  { _id: 1, f1: "senior", f2: "manager" },
  { _id: 2, f1: "junior", f2: "manager" },
  { _id: 3, f1: "fresher", f2: "developer" },
  { _id: 4, f1: "manager", f2: "senior" }
]
```

#### Aggregation Query 1:

- `$addFields` to add new field `matchResult` for matching status in boolean

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      matchResult: {
        $and: [
```

- first `$or` condition match if `f1` or `f2` fields match `senior` then return `true` other wise return `false`

```
          {
            $or: [
              { $regexMatch: { input: "$f1", regex: "senior", options: "x" } },
              { $regexMatch: { input: "$f2", regex: "senior", options: "x" } }
            ]
          },
```

- second `$or` condition match if `f1` or `f2` fields match `manager` then return `true` other wise return `false`

```
          {
            $or: [
              { $regexMatch: { input: "$f1", regex: "manager", options: "x" } },
              { $regexMatch: { input: "$f2", regex: "manager", options: "x" } }
            ]
          }
```

```
        ]
      }
    }
  },
```

- `$match` condition return result that have `matchResult` is equal to `true`

```
  { $match: { matchResult: true } }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/QyL7QovRbZp)

#### Aggregation Query 2:

- if you are not using array fields then this is sort way, directly you can concat all fields on one field, here i have merged `f1` and `f2` with space in `allField`

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      allField: { $concat: ["$f1", " ", "$f2"] }
    }
  },
```

- this will match `$and` condition on both word match if both true then return true otherwise false

```
  {
    $addFields: {
      matchResult: {
        $and: [
          { $regexMatch: { input: "$allField", regex: "senior", options: "x" } },
          { $regexMatch: { input: "$allField", regex: "manager", options: "x" } }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
```

- `$match` condition return result that have `matchResult` is equal to `true`

```
  { $match: { matchResult: true } }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/FlZ1Z4FPZlQ)

> **Note:** This is alternate approach for limited fields, but imaging if more then 5 fields then it affects speed and performance of the query.

Comment: Dang, the biggest problem is that we have lots of fields on a document, so $text is basically necessary to search all of them at once (and do all of its fancy word stemming, etc.)

Comment: I can just keep using multiple `find()` operations with `$text` to get the results then. Back to the main question then I guess -- I have more unrelated processing stages further down the aggregation pipeline (mainly more `$addFields` to modify the result score based on other criteria). Is there a stage to import the `$text` results into that pipeline, or do aggregations always have to start with the entire collection?

Comment: yes you are right, that i already mentioned, this is a option for limited fields, and with $text its is not possible.

Comment: i don't know but might be your 2 queries are good solution.. and there are many restriction on $text you can read in question link.